# Extend JWT time in c#

Tags: c#, jwt

I have this filter (below) and I want to extend the time of the token (by replacing the token and re-writing a new one for the user) ... Can anybody help me achieve this?

This is the standard filter without any custom changes or anything, I've already handled token expiry, now I want to renew the token when a request is made within token expiry time

```
public class JwtAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public string Realm { get; set; }
    public bool AllowMultiple => false;

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

        if (authorization == null || authorization.Scheme != "Bearer")
            return;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Missing Jwt Token", request);
            return;
        }

        var token = authorization.Parameter;
        var principal = await AuthenticateJwtToken(token);

        if (principal == null)
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid token", request);

        else
            context.Principal = principal;

          // HERE SHOULD BE THE IMPLEMENTATION FOR TOKEN RENEWAL
    }



    private static bool ValidateToken(string token, out string username)
    {
        username = null;

        var simplePrinciple = JwtManager.GetPrincipal(token);
        var identity = simplePrinciple?.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        if (identity == null)
            return false;

        if (!identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        var usernameClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);
        username = usernameClaim?.Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            return false;

        // More validate to check whether username exists in system

        return true;
    }

    protected Task<IPrincipal> AuthenticateJwtToken(string token)
    {
        string username;

        if (ValidateToken(token, out username))
        {
            // based on username to get more information from database in order to build local identity
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
                // Add more claims if needed: Roles, ...
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Jwt");
            IPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            return Task.FromResult(user);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<IPrincipal>(null);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Challenge(context);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private void Challenge(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context)
    {
        string parameter = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Realm))
            parameter = "realm=\"" + Realm + "\"";

        context.ChallengeWith("Bearer", parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: in jwt there is no such thing as "extending the time". Since your payload is changing with a new expiration date so will the digital signature. invalidate the token and issue a new one, just like you issued the original token

Comment: @Daniel I know, I'll re-issue a new token, but how can I resend it back to the client side? before the request hits the controller?

Comment: How are you issuing the original token? if cookie just replace the cookie

Comment: @Daniel by extracting the user data from the old token and writing a new token from it.

Comment: let me rephrase my question, in what format are you serving the token to the client? cookie? response body?

Comment: @Daniel It's saved in local storage, not cookie

Comment: Why are storing the JWT token in the UI instead of keeping it tied to the session instead ? This way the sessionId should be enough.

Comment: You can create a keep alive endpoint that pool new token right before expiration